# print pdf from iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript

While running time I'm adding pdf in iframe dynamically and printing that iframe.

But it's showing Permission denied error

This is my code

```
    g_iFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
    g_iFrame.id = "testFrame";
    var style = g_iFrame.style;
    style.border = "1px solid black";
    style.width = "300px";
    style.height = "200px";
    g_iFrame.src = "D:\\Testing\\PDF\\"+mYFileList[i][0];

    document.body.appendChild(g_iFrame);
    var iframe = document.getElementById('testFrame');
    var frm = iframe.contentWindow;
    frm.focus();
    frm.print();
```

Note : mYFileList[i][0] is my pdf file from array

Comment: `D:\\\` is a no-no... put it on the server and link to it's url.

Comment: Is this server-side or client-side? Which OS?

Comment: D:// implies windows, and getElementById implies client side..

Comment: server means local or something

Comment: @Iwr ... It's the asker's work to specify the question clearly, not answerers to guess the requirements.

Comment: client side only and Win 7 OS

Comment: @user202729 - it's not a guess, there's no dom in client side js and *nix based oses don't name their drives like that..

Comment: Try opening `file:///D:/` and ``D:\\`` in your browser. Which one works?

Comment: file is opening in iframe correctly. but while printing only it's showing permission denied error

Comment: Both of this ( file:///D:/ and D:\\  ) working

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox you face this ? [See this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911444)

I have built a way around, not perfect yet.
Need to effectively use window.postMessage ([this can be helpful](http://pbojinov.github.io/iframe-communication/)) to confirm pdf loaded, before printing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
g_iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
g_iframe.id = "testFrame";
var style = g_iframe.style;
style.padding = "0px";
g_iframe.width = "960px";
style.height = "1100px";
g_iframe.src = "D:\\Testing\\PDF\\"+mYFileList[i][0];


g_iframe.addEventListener('load', function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("iframe[id='testFrame']").html('<script type="text/javascript"> window.print(); </script>');
    }, 2000); 
}, true);

document.body.appendChild(g_iframe);
```

});